# Is there any legitimacy to hearing "So long, d**kheads?" on Admiral Ackbar’s ship at the end of “Return of the Jedi?”

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

A persistent internet rumor has been that in *Return of the Jedi* (1983), after the Super Star Destroyer Executor is destroyed and the audience sees the reaction on the bridge of *Home One*, you can hear someone in the background yell

> "So long, dickheads!"

Every once in a while, someone on social media will comment on this, but is there any legitimacy to this idea, or is this simply a case of people hearing what they want to hear? If so, what is the origin of this rumor?

You can "hear" the quote at around 00:41-00:43 in this video.

Comment: I just listened at the timestamp you mentioned and heard it. Do you not hear it?

Comment: Sounds to me like a "Wehey!". I can't hear any articulated words there. @Derek

Comment: @Derek I hear it, but I don't know if it's because it's actually there or because I'm conditioned to hear it.

Comment: I hear a sequence of vowel sounds that match the vowels in the supposed quote but the other cheering obscures the consonants enough that I would never feel certain. From what I hear it could just as easily be “So long, Piett!” Referring to the Admiral in command of the super star destroyer.

Comment: It sounds to me like "Wahoo, we got 'em!"

Comment: That genuinely made me laugh out loud.